# How to execute click() on this hyperlink using selenium 3

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

This is HTML code of page:

```
<a href="default_Usuario.asp?i=1"><img src="resources/v3_presioneaqui.gif" border="0"></a>
```

I tried with this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href ='default_Usuario.asp?i=1']")).click();
```

but it didn't work for me gives error NoSuchElementException

Comment: Try this Xpath `.//a[@href='default_Usuario.asp?i=1']/img`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it didn't work for me gives error NoSuchElementException

There could be following reasons for this `exception` as below :-

- May be your trying locator to locate element is not correct, you're using to locate exact value of `href` attribute which could be change dynamically. You should try with partial match using `cssSelector` as :-

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='default_Usuario']")).click();
  ```
- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible on `DOM` and clickable as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href*='default_Usuario']")));
  el.click();
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame/iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame/iframe` before finding the desired element as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

  //Wait until frame/iframe to available and then switch to it
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("your frame id or name"));

  //Now find the desired element 
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href*='default_Usuario']")));
  el.click();

  //Once all your stuff done with this frame/iframe need to switch back to default for further stuff
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  ```

Comment: If this answer helped need to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as well..

Answer (score 0):

You should try for a more general selector like this one:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'default_Usuario')]
```